# Is there a utility in Symfony framework that will monitor for any changes in your source and automatically restart your server?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to Symfony php framework & I'm looking for utility like nodemon in Nodejs that automatically listens to changes done in codebase and updates/restart the server. Is there anyway to get this done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `php` in general there is no such need: it is a script language meaning that every time script is requested it is interpreted from scratch (it's bit simplified truth). So every time you edit your php file it is "live" right away - no need of server restart (like in `node.js`, `asp.net` etc)